# How do I subclass NSTableRow in NSOutlineView

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

To change the `NSOutlineView` sidebar highlight colour, `NSTableRow` needs to be subclassed with an `override func drawSelectionInRect`. How is this possible when there is currently no exposed reference to `NSTableRow` in code?

```
func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewForTableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: AnyObject) -> NSView? {

}
```

---

Perhaps there is potential in using a simpler solution with the `emphazised` property

```
func outlineViewSelectionDidChange(notification: NSNotification){
    let selectedIndex = notification.object?.selectedRow
    let object:AnyObject? = notification.object?.itemAtRow(selectedIndex!)
    notification.object?.rowViewAtRow(selectedIndex!, makeIfNecessary: false)?.emphasized = false
    outlineView.deselectRow(selectedIndex!)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as you use

```
func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewForTableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: AnyObject) -> NSView? {...}
```

you can use

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, rowViewForItem item: AnyObject) -> NSTableRowView? {...}
```

for rowViews.

Here is how you do it:

1. Subclass `NSTableRowView` and implement `drawSelectionInRect:` to customize the appearance of your subclass.
2. Make sure that your outlineView knows about your subclass by returning it in `rowViewForItem:`
   You can see how to return the view in this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19260707/4113940).

Since you only override drawSelectionInRect: every other functionality will still be available. So you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: Thank you Max. How do I implement this method while keeping its existing behaviour?

Comment: What do you mean with existing behavior?