# Seemless backgroundcolor for a NSTableView Row

Tags: macos, nstableview

I want to create a seamless background color a tableview row, however I see it breaks at the end of the cell which I suspect is the part where the imageView is. what is the best way to have a continuous color on the whole row of the NSTableView just like the alternatingRow color? This is what I get when I do

```
    cellView.wantsLayer = YES;
    cellView.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor].CGColor;
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coloring rows in View based NSTableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910779/coloring-rows-in-view-based-nstableview)

Comment: yes it does!!! Thankyou.

Comment: Thanks to @Willeke the solution is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910779/coloring-rows-in-view-based-nstableview